# form_with doesn't post all data in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm building a web application for booking tours by rails 6, I'm stuck when I try to create a booking model by post data from the tour's view to the booking controller.
This is my code to do this.
On tour's view:

```
<%= form_with url: bookings_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :tour_id, value: @tour.id %>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :adults %>
    <div class="buttons_added">
      <input class="minus is-form" onclick="decrease('adults', <%= @tour.price %>);" type="button" value="-">
      <%= f.number_field :adults, class: "input-qty", value: "1", max: "100", min: "0", id: "adults", disabled: true %>
      <input class="plus is-form" onclick="increase('adults', <%= @tour.price %>);" type="button" value="+">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :children %>
    <div class="buttons_added">
      <input class="minus is-form" onclick="decrease('child', <%= @tour.price %>);" type="button" value="-">
      <%= f.number_field :children, class: "input-qty", value: "0", max: "100", min: "0", id: "child", disabled: true %>
      <input class="plus is-form" onclick="increase('child', <%= @tour.price %>);" type="button" value="+">
    </div>
  </div>
            
  <%= f.label :date_begin %>
  <%= f.date_field :date_begin, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.number_field :total, id: "total", value: @tour.price, disabled: true %>
  <%= f.submit t("tour.show.booking"), class: "button mt1 btn btn-danger", disabled: !@tour.status %>
<% end %>
```

Js:

```
<script>

  var decrease = function(id, price) {

    var total = document.getElementById("total");
        var tag = document.getElementById(id);
        var qty = tag.value;
    if (id == "adults" && qty == "1") return false;
        if (!isNaN(qty) && qty >= 1) {
      tag.value--;
      total.value = parseInt(total.value) - ((id == "adults") ? price : (price / 2));
    }

        return false;
    }

    var increase = function(id, price) {

    var total = document.getElementById("total");
        var tag = document.getElementById(id);
        var qty = tag.value;

        if (!isNaN(qty)) {

      tag.value++;
          total.value = parseInt((id == "adults") ? price : (price / 2)) + parseInt(total.value);
    }

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

When I post data, only **tour_id** and **date_start** passed, although I have permitted those.

```
def booking_params
    params.permit(:tour_id, :total, :adults, :children, :date_begin)
end
```

There is what I find in my server when I try to debug:

> {"tour_id"=>"1", "date_begin"=>"2021-08-18"}
> Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :commit, :locale

Comment: Use readonly instead of disabled inputs otherwise use hidden fields along with disabled inputs to display the values to the user

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because browser doesn't submit disabled inputs.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled